# Python: How to subtract only corresponding values from lists in a for Loop

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract sold stock from the total stock, however using this code, it subtracts each value in list B from each value in list A.

I want the corresponding value in list B to be subtracted from its corresponding value in list A, then move to the next set of numbers, opposed to subtracting every value from list B from each value in list A.

I am unsure how to modify my code, how do I achieve this?

```
for s in stocks:
    for q in quantities:
        print(float(s) - float(q))
```

**what I want:**

```
stock: [10, 20, 30]
quantities: [2, 3, 4]

output: 8, 17, 26
```

**what is occurring:**

```
stock: [10, 20, 30]
quantities: [2, 3, 4]

output: 8, 7, 6, 18, 17, 16, 28, 27, 26
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
print([int(x) - int(y) for x, y in zip(stock, quantities)])
```

Output:

```
[8, 17, 26]
```

Or if you want a loop:

```
for x, y in zip(stock, quantities):
    print(int(x) - int(y))
```

Output:

```
8
17
26
```

Here is the [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/zip.html):

> Returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

Or use a `map`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x, y: int(x) - int(y), stock, quantities)))
```

Output:

```
[8, 17, 26]
```

Here is the [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/map.html):

> Applies function to every item of an iterable and returns a list of the results.
>   Your code isn't working because your doing something like:

`10 - 2, 10 - 3, 10 - 4, 20 - 2` and so on...

So you're iterating through `stock`, and you're subtracting it by each value in `quantities`, not just the corresponding value.

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried that but it doesnt seem to work. x and y are both strings so they cant be subtracted, using print(float(x) - float(y)) doesnt seem to work either as it prints out '2.0' and '-6.0'

Comment: @18649626842568 Try now, i edited my answer, please accept it if it works

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a dictionary to store your data in the first place, but for your use case, try using:

```
output = [int(stock[x]) - int(quantities[x]) for x, s in enumerate(stock)]
```

Comment: Why an `enumerate` then, just use a `range`.

Comment: Enumerate let's you get the index of the list. Range would also work, but you wouldn't be able to access the value at each index.

Comment: I know what you mean, but currently you're not using the value of the list, only the index

Comment: thanks for replying, x and y are both strings and it doesn't let me subtract them

Comment: Try it with the edit.